# React router shows blank page when i clicked menu in dashboard

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have 2 pages, in my homepage  there's a route to render login, register, and dashboard page and in my dashboard there a route to render content if i click the sidebar menu. 
the problem is if i clicked the sidebar menu to render content, it renders blank page.

my homepage

```
  render() {
    return(
        <Switch>

            <Route path ="/home" exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginForm}/>
            <Route path="/register/" exact component={RegisterForm}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={dashboard}/>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home"/>
        </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

my dashboard

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <NavBar />
        <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
          <SidebarMenu />
        </aside>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            //my content
            <Route path="/dashboard/userlist" exact component={ListUser}/>
        </div>
</div>
```

i only want render the content without rendering the sidebar menu.but it shows blank page like its move back to homepage .
if i put route path="/dashboard/userlist" in my homepage , its work but he render everthing i only want render the content.

im still learning to use this react router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you redirect to "/dashboard/userlist" it goes through your switch statement and since there is no match it will redirect to hom, meaning it goes through your redirect component.

bring your

```
 <Route path="/dashboard/userlist" exact component={ListUser}/>
```

on top of

```
 <Route path="/dashboard" component={dashboard}/>
```

and add "exact" to this one as well.

```
<Route path="/dashboard" exact component={dashboard}/>
```

so it should be like this

```
<Switch>
    <Route path ="/home" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginForm}/>
    <Route path="/register/" exact component={RegisterForm}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard/userlist" exact component={ListUser}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={dashboard}/>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home"/>
</Switch>
```

try this and let me know if you have more question.

Comment: its working , but its render everything . i only want render the content without rendering the menu dashboard